# Testvectors for dedicated hardware miner

Tags: protocol, bitcoind, testnet

I have written my own hardware implementation for hash computation. I am participating in a pool, that is I get sent the midstate and some data which should then be hashed.

I wonder, whether there are any testvectors out there, that is I need input the midstate plus data, and see then whether my implementation finds the appropriate nonce that is also supplied with the testvectors.

Many thanks for your help,
Patrick

Comment: New implementation, cool! CPU/GPU? Why don't you test it on a real pool?

Answer (score 1):

The block headers in the blockchain are your test vectors, they already contain the appropriate nonce. Midstate can be computed from these headers, mining software does such a midstate computation (so crib this bit from their source code).